# How to generate an External ID based ID's that has negative value on price

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have this Data set

```
InvoiceID     CDamount   companyname
   1             2500       NASA
   1            -2500       NASA
   2             1600       Airjet
   3             5000       Boeing
   4            -600        EXEarth
   5             8000       SpaceX
   5            -8000       SpaceX
```

I want to be able to get that as shown below:

```
External ID    CDamount   companyname
   1             2500       NASA
   1-C          -2500       NASA
   2             1600       Airjet
   3             5000       Boeing
   4            -600        EXEarth
   5             8000       SpaceX
   5-C          -8000       SpaceX
```

I cannot use  CASE WHEN CDamount < 0 THEN InvoiceID + '-' + 'C' ELSE InvoiceID END AS "External ID" because some of other companies have negative amount as well that do not fall under this category.

I was wondering how can I say IF InvoiceID is Duplicated AND CDAmount is Negative then Create a new External ID?

Is this something possible?

Below you can create the sample data

```
Create Table #Incident (
InvoiceID int,
CDamount int,
Companyname Nvarchar(255))


insert into #Incident Values (1,2500,'NASA')
insert into #Incident Values (1,-2500,'NASA')
insert into #Incident Values (2,1600,'Airjet')
insert into #Incident Values (3, 5000, 'Boeing')
insert into #Incident Values (4, -600, 'ExEarth')
insert into #Incident Values (5,8000,'SpaceX')
insert into #Incident Values (5, -8000, 'SpaceX')
```

Here is What I used but as I mentioned since ID number 4 has negative value as well I get "-C" for it which I do not want to.

```
Select CASE WHEN T1.CDamount < 0 
            THEN  CAST(T1.InvoiceID AS nvarchar (255)) + '-' + 'C' 
            ELSE CAST(T1.InvoiceID AS nvarchar (255)) 
        END AS ExternalID,
T1.Companyname 
from #Incident AS T1
```

Comment: _"because some of other companies have negative amount as well that do not fall under this category"_  Then you need to provide an actual example and describe the logic to identify such rows. Trying to write code by reading your mind is not terribly effective. And are you assuming that there will be no more than 2 rows for any given InvoiceID? Is that a **safe** assumption?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SMor Invoice ID number 4 is an example of that. they have negative amount but Id is not duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

So I got this based on my knowledge of SQL and that works for my case.
Not sure if it is an smart way to go with but can be a good start for someone who is struggling with a Scenario like this:

```
;With CTE1 AS (
SELECT Count(*) AS Duplicate, T1.InvoiceID 
From #Incident AS T1
Group by T1.InvoiceID
),
Main AS (
Select CASE WHEN  T1.CDamount < 0 AND T2.Duplicate > 1
            THEN  CAST(T1.InvoiceID AS nvarchar (255)) + '-' + 'C' 
            ELSE CAST(T1.InvoiceID AS nvarchar (255)) 
        END AS ExternalID,
        T1.InvoiceID AS count,
        T1.CDamount,
T1.Companyname 
from #Incident AS T1
Join CTE1 AS T2 ON T1.InvoiceID = T2.InvoiceID
)
SELECT * FROM Main
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution without CTE, using ROW_NUMBER() function.

```
SELECT
          CASE WHEN CDAmount < 0 AND RowID > 1
            THEN InvoiceID + '-C'
            ELSE InvoiceID
          END AS ExternalID
        , CDAmount
        , CompanyName
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                      CAST(InvoiceID AS NVARCHAR(255)) AS InvoiceID
                    , CDAmount
                    , CompanyName
                    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceID ORDER BY CompanyName) AS RowID
                FROM
                    #Incident
        ) AS SourceTable
```

The trick is using ROW_NUMBER() function to generate a sequence which resets when InvoiceID changes. Here's the subquery and its result. Use CASE statement when CDAmount is negative and RowID greater than 1.

```
SELECT
          CAST(InvoiceID AS NVARCHAR(255)) AS InvoiceID
        , CDAmount
        , CompanyName
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceID ORDER BY CompanyName) AS RowID
    FROM
        #Incident
```

Subquery result:

```
+-----------+----------+-------------+-------+
| InvoiceID | CDAmount | CompanyName | RowID |
+-----------+----------+-------------+-------+
|         1 |     2500 | NASA        |     1 |
|         1 |    -2500 | NASA        |     2 |
|         2 |     1600 | Airjet      |     1 |
|         3 |     5000 | Boeing      |     1 |
|         4 |     -600 | ExEarth     |     1 |
|         5 |     8000 | SpaceX      |     1 |
|         5 |    -8000 | SpaceX      |     2 |
+-----------+----------+-------------+-------+
```